# VBA-Word: Apply multiple paragraph formatting

Tags: vba, macros, ms-word

I'm trying to work on my first (and hopefully the last) Macro on Word and I have come to a dead-end. As I am working a lot between Word and Word Online the formatting tends to change so I need to create a Macro that will save me the trouble of re-adjusting it manually.

My problem is that I need to have different spacing on my body text based on the font used (for Arial to have spacing before 6 and for Courier New that we use for code spacing before 0). I have tried to create the code using the Macro Recorder and the Replace function but the recorder gives me a generic code that doesn't specify the font I need (although I choose it) so when I run both I end up with the Arial formatting on both. Here is the code I get for the Courier New:

```
Sub FormatBodyCode()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find.Replacement.ParagraphFormat
    .SpaceBefore = 0
    .SpaceBeforeAuto = False
    .SpaceAfter = 0
    .SpaceAfterAuto = False
    .LineSpacingRule = wdLineSpaceMultiple
    .LineSpacing = LinesToPoints(1.15)
    .Alignment = wdAlignParagraphLeft
    .OutlineLevel = wdOutlineLevelBodyText
    .LineUnitBefore = 0
    .LineUnitAfter = 0
End With
With Selection.Find
    .Text = ""
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

How can I specify the font to make it work?

Comment: Hopefully not the last!  Welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) for more about asking questions that will attract quality answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One quick code change should restrict the search for a single font:

```
...
With Selection.Find
    ...
    .Format = True 
    .Font.Name = "Courier New"    ' <== Add this - Or whatever font you want
    ...
```

The easiest way to do multiple fonts is to copy the whole function to another function with a different name and change the font name and spacing in the other function.

Comment: It was that simple, huh? I still can't understand why it didn't include it in the recorder though.